# URL convention for date range

Tags: friendly-url, date-range

What would be the accepted convention for displaying a date range in a friendly URL?

For example, in a time tracking application. Instead of using the database's primary key for a specific pay period in the URL, I would like to use something more easily distinguishable to the user.

```
http://www.mytimesheet.com/11-1-2009-11-14-2009
http://www.mytimesheet.com/period-beginning-11-1-2009
```

Neither of those seem to cut it, but maybe I'm just being overly critical.

Comment: why is this MVC related?

Comment: It's not specifically, so tag removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you considered ISO format dates, especially in their compact form: `YYYYMMDD`, then it should be possible to have:

```
http://example.com/dates/20091101/20091131
```

Specifically I don't think there is any *accepted* convention for this.

Edit: this is about routing as well...

Comment: This seems like the cleanest solution I've seen, and the most straightforward outside of a query string.

Comment: +1. Can include the `-`s too if you want; if you do use hyphens you should *always* be using ISO8601 YYYY-MM-DD ordering.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's up to you, but I like the idea of

```
http://foo.com/bar/from/2008/
http://foo.com/bar/from/2008/10/
http://foo.com/bar/from/2008/10/02
```

Or, it can be combined with something like `/between/2008/10/2009/10` and such.

Comment: I prefer this method, as it makes the address much more 'human readable/explorable'

Comment: I'd like to offer an alternate preference to: `http://foo.com/bar/from/2014-09-01/`. It implies a date similar to the written form. Would you say this is more human readable?

Answer (score 1):

I'd either use something like:

```
http://www.mytimesheet.com/start/11-1-2009/end/11-14-2009
```

or

```
http://www.mytimesheet.com?start=11-1-2009&end=11-14-2009
```

But what daniel says, you could convert this in a post so you hide it altogether, if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think this is the sort of data that is best POSTed, rather than used to specify a route.

*(sometimes if the solution seems broken in this way, then maybe the approach is incorrect.)*

However, if you really want to specify dates, perhaps you should consider a format that is more likely to be understood in a consistent way in all cultures, such as yyyy-mmm-dd  (e.g. 2009-nov-11)

Comment: POST seems like a really bad idea here, as it would break pretty much any kind of UI exprience (no bookmarking, no reloading without an anoying popup if at all, no back button). A GET query is a lot better for..., well, queries. Only use POST when you're actually changing something (like updating a database record), which should not be allowed to do twice.

Comment: Also no sending a URL to a friend/colleague/etc over instant messaging or email, that's something that really bugs me. :)